# Differences in Tochacha (rebuke) between Ki Tavo and Behukotai

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rebuke-tochacha, ki-tavo, bechukosai

As I understand, one of the main differences between the rebuke in parshat *Bekhukotai* and parshat *Ki Tavo* is that the earlier one is spoken by G-d and the later one is spoken by Moshe, as is the majority of Devarim.

A reading of the one in *Ki Tavo* reveals far more punishments and calamities than those mentioned in *Behukotai*. Where does Moshe know that these things will happen? Are these a form of *nevu'ah* meaning that G-d told him these things and now he is relaying it?

Additionally, in the Behukotai *tochacha*, we find interspersed a few verses of hope and encouragement such as [Vayikra 26:42](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14081&st=&pgnum=393&hilite=). (Related that this is "encouragement is Kitzur S.A.'s halacha that the Torah reader should raise his voice for this verse.) *Ki Tavo* has no words of encouragement in the middle. Why does Moshe not offer any?

Comment: Ki Savo does end the sixth aliyah with a couple of encouraging sentences, right after the curses. But I presume this is because you never end an Aliyah on a negative note.

Comment: @MarkFischler Your assumption is correct. We also prefer not to begin an aliyah on a bad note. However, within my question, I wasn't referring to the aliyah as much as the parsha (actaul written paragraph.) Within the single paragraph containing the *tochacha* of *Ki Tavo*, there are no encouraging words, unlike what you see in *Behukotai*. In Ki Tavo, the last verse of the aliyah is its own parsha.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Frand in [The Difference Between The Two Tochachas](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5772-netzavim/) cites [Rav Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) as saying that the consolation appears in Parsha Nitzavim rather than immediately after the tochacha in Ki Savo.

> Rav Yosha Baer Soloveitchik, z”l, asks: Why the difference? Rav Yosha
>   Baer answers that in fact the Tochacha in Ki Savo also ends with
>   consolation… except the consolation only appears in Parshas Netzavim:
>   “And it shall come to pass, when all these things are come upon you,
>   the blessing and the curse, that I have presented before you – then
>   you will take it to your heart among all the nations where Hashem,
>   your G-d, has dispersed you. And you will return unto Hashem, your
>   G-d, and listen to His voice, according to everything that I command
>   you today, you and your children, with all your heart and all your
>   soul. [Devorim 30:1-2] The consolation is that at the end of all the
>   punishment and suffering, the Jewish people will do Teshuva [repent]
>   and return to G-d.

This still leaves the question as to why the delay until Nitzavim. R
explains that the Rav Soloveitchik explains that the tochacha in
Bechukosai foretells the destruction of the first Bais Hamikdash, whose
exile was foretold to be 70 years. The destruction of the Second
Temple, foretold in Ki Savo caused our current exile, which will end
at some point, but we cannot know when that will be.

> But the question can still be asked: Why is it that in the Tochacha in
>   Devorim, there is a pause and we have to “wait for the consolation”,
>   so to speak, while in the Tochacha in Bechukosai, the consolation
>   comes immediately? Rav Soloveitchik answers this question by
>   explaining that there is a fundamental difference between the two
>   Tochachas. The Ramba”n says that the Tochacha in Bechukosai foretells
>   and refers to the period of the destruction of the First Bais
>   HaMikdash and the exile from the Land of Israel at that time. The
>   Tochacha foretold in Ki Savo refers to the destruction of the Second
>   Bais HaMikdash and the exile that occurred at that time. The
>   Destruction of the First Bais HaMikdash and the Babylonian exile which
>   followed it had a prophesized finite end to it. The prophets foretold
>   that the people would be in exile for 70 years and indeed following
>   this 70 year period, the Jews were given permission to return to the
>   Land of Israel (where they eventually rebuilt the Bais HaMikdash).
>   Therefore, it makes sense that the Tochacha which foretells the
>   Babylonian Exile features the consolation in close proximity to the
>   end of the pasukim of chastisement.
>
> As we now know, we do not know of a specified date for the redemption
>   from the Destruction of the Second Bais HaMikdash. We have now been in
>   this exile for close to 2000 years! However, there will be an end to
>   this exile. As the Rambam writes in the Laws of Repentance: “Israel
>   will only be redeemed through repentance. The prophets have already
>   promised that the Jews will repent at the end of their exile and
>   immediately thereafter they will be redeemed, as it is written…” (and
>   then the Rambam quotes the pasuk in this week’s parsha) “…And it will
>   be that when all these things come upon you… you will return unto
>   Hashem your G-d.”
>
> When will that occur? We do not know, but it will come. This is
>   precisely why the consolation does not immediately follow the Tochacha
>   here in Devorim. We need to wait. We need to wait until we return to
>   the L-rd our G-d. We are going to be in the mess in which we find
>   ourselves until we do Teshuva.
>
> This is the difference between the two Tochachas. In the first, we
>   just had to wait a (relatively) short time. When the clock struck 70,
>   we were able to go home. The current exile is not like that.
>   Eventually, we will get out of it because “in the end Israel will
>   repent and immediately thereafter they will be redeemed” but we do not
>   know when that is going to happen.